# Bundler refuses to work with correct gem's SSL and proxy configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm working behind an enterprise proxy server, for which I (seemingly) implemented the correct configurations in order to work with my company's own proxy root certificates.

I added the certificates to the *.\Ruby26-x64\lib\ruby\site_ruby\2.6.0\rubygems\ssl_certs* folder and
adapted the *.gemrc* file with the **http_proxy** and **https_proxy** configuration.

Now commands like `gem install hirb` work like a charm, but when i try to run `bundler install` or `bunler update` on a Rails project, it fails with:

> Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
> Resolving dependencies...
> Could not verify the SSL certificate for
> https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/puma-4.3.4.gemspec.rz.
> There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most
> likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
> information about OpenSSL certificates, see http://bit. ly/ruby-ssl. To connect
> without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.

I tried quite some different solutions to no avail, also setting the source to http://rubymine.org
is not a feasable solution.

System Specs:

- Windows 10
- Ruby with Devkit 2.6.6
- Rails 6.0.3.2
- Bundler 1.17.2
- Yarn 1.22.4

How the hell can I tell bundle to trust my company's self-signed root certs?

DISMISSED SOLUTIONS SO FAR:

1. Define `:ssl_verify_mode: 0` in `.gemrc` seems to be completely ignored
2. Define `BUNDLE_SSL_CA_CERT` and have it pointing to gem's `.../ssl_certs/rubygems.org` directory containing my CA certs, also has no effect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error) Specifically, you want the answer about `.gemrc` including the line `:ssl_verify_mode: 0` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10250470/3784008

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried `:ssl_verify_mode: 0`.
Bundler just ignores it, and throws the same error.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/3877055/3784008 help?

Comment: No. The problem is with the SSL verification, proxy addresses seem to be picked up correctly, otherwise, I wouldn't be able to reach `rubygems.org` at all and the error would be different, specifically I would get timeout warnings, etc...